# 2 driver available via jockey

Tags: jockey

i installed my Nvidia proprietary driver.
 
but i have another that remains uninstalled. and i don't know whether
 
i have to install that to or no.
 
cause the description isnt that different from the driver i installed

here is what i mean (its in dutch sorry)

[image: driver]

install the second one post-release update?, or no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are two alternative versions of the Nvidia driver.
You currently have the 'nvidia-current' package installed which is stable and preferred over the other one (a beta version).
You can't install both. If you choose the 'post-release' it will replace the 'current'.